# Github new project add

Tags: git, github, upload, project

Good Day:
I am new to github. I have created a repo. I want to upload the whole project to github; my project has a lot of folders and sub-folders. To do that I have followed [this gide](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git)
Now I have my Repo and I have been able to upload the Readme file, but I'm unable to upload the rest of the code, I do not know how to say to github that my whole folder should be uploaded.
any advice?
Regards

Comment: Do use `push/pull`? It's like upload/download.

Comment: thi is the command: `root@khs01wxl001:/var/www/Symfony# git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': my user
Password for 'https://aguzmans@github.com': 
Everything up-to-date
root@khs01wxl001:/var/www/Symfony# ` as it is explained in the gide that I mentioned. But it only uploades the READme file.

Comment: Edit your answer with the results from `git status` and `git branch` please. It sounds like you've only committed `README` on `master` which is the one that you pushed.

Comment: when I run git status it lists (I think) every single file in my  Project... this are part of those files listed: `# new file:   web/bundles/framework/css/body.css
# new file:   web/bundles/framework/css/exception.css
# new file:   web/bundles/framework/css/structure.css `. and git branch shows * master.

Comment: When you run `git status` it tells you whether they're new files or if you've staged them or if they're all already committed, which is all the stuff that you assumed wasn't worth pasting in. It's not about what files are there but what they're listed as. The problem is that you didn't add them or commit them, only committed the change to `README`, so that's all that got pushed.

Comment: which are the commands you have tried and executed

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the directory structure of your github, I'm guessing that you didn't add your folders and sub-folders into your repo.
To expand on the previous answer...
cp -rf [source folder] [repo] 
git add .
git status *//this should show all your folders and sub-folders*
git commit -am "init"
git push origin master *//or your branch name if it's not master*

Comment: this was what was missing: `git commit -am "init"` I do not know what is it (now I'll read about it),  now it is uploading. thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

What should you do:

1. Create repo on github
2. Clone it on your local env by http/ssh url
3. Copy all your files into that repo
4. Add them
5. Commit
6. Push them to github (enter your login and pass if http)

Do you follow such procedure?